# fitsSystemWindows makes my Translucent statusbar gray

Tags: android

In my `styles.xml`, the theme of the app has the following properties:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
 </style>
```

If `android:fitsSystemWindows` is `false`, my `statusbar` will be transparent, but some layouts will not fit right on the screen. So to make the layouts fit the screen I put `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `true`, which then makes everything fit right. But the statusbar becomes gray as in the picture below.

What is it, that I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding `fitsSystemWindow` to entire theme, just use that on only the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since this was asked but I'm on the same stand right now and, what I did to overcome this problem was:
1) Remove all android:fitsSystemWindows from both styles and layouts (xml)
2) Programmatically calculate the height of the status bar
3) Apply a padding top with the calculated value for the status bar on root viewgroups

To calculate the statusbar height I used the following snippet. This was brought from some website who's author I can't remember right now (Sorry about that..)

```
public static int getStatusBarHeight(Activity activity) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out

Comment: This is a very bad piece of advice, as given by one of the actual Google engineers where he *specifically* talks about this copy-pasted code from all over the place. Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE